# Full Calendar drag and drop event call back

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, draggable, fullcalendar-4

*When i try to add external event to it i require date and time from the calendar how can i achieve that here is my code which i have worked over*.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
        var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable

        //// the individual way to do it
        var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events-list');
        var eventEls = Array.prototype.slice.call(
          containerEl.querySelectorAll('.fc-event')
        );
        eventEls.forEach(function(eventEl) {
          new Draggable(eventEl, {
            eventData: {
                title: eventEl.innerText.trim(),
              }, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
              drop: function (arg) {
                  // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                  alert(arg);
              }, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
              eventReceive: function (arg) {
                  // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                  alert(arg);
              },
              eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                  //inner column movement drop so get start and call the ajax function......
                  console.log(event.start.format());
                  console.log(event.id);
                  var defaultDuration = moment.duration($('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'defaultTimedEventDuration'));
                  var end = event.end || event.start.clone().add(defaultDuration);
                  console.log('end is ' + end.format());

                  //alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());

              }
          });
        });

        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            drop: function (arg) {
                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if (document.getElementById('drop-remove').checked) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    arg.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(arg.draggedEl);
                }
            },
            eventDrop: function (info) {
                alert(info.event.title + " was dropped on " + info.event.start.toISOString());

                if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                    info.revert();
                }
            },
            //eventRender: function (info) {
            //    console.log(info.event.extendedProps);
            //    // {description: "Lecture", department: "BioChemistry"}
            //}
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

*i am trying to add event callback function in the **new Draggable** but to no use as event are not fired from it when **i drag within the calendar** then it fires back from **new Calendar**, so i require that after dragging event externally in the calendar i need to get date and time from it.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204087/discussion-on-question-by-namco-full-calendar-drag-and-drop-event-call-back).